# How to implement Reflect XSS fix in webforms .net 2.0 Application

Tags: .net, application-security

I have started working on a webforms application built in `.net 2.0` using `VS 2005`. I am kind of new to web application

When I am clicking on a `Menu item` which is `<li/>` tag and capture the request in `burp` and Changed the Url to `"obgv0%22%3e%3cscript%3ealert('XSS HACKED')%3c%2fscript%3et48bw"`

Here I am getting getting a `pop-up-"XSS HACKED"` and it indicates that it is vulnerable.

I tried to find exact solution of this problem on net. but unlucky so far.

1. So please help me in solving it

I tried to replicate the scenario in `VS 2015` by creating an empty web application. but it seems `Microsoft` put a permanent fix for this. If someone can guide me the way `Microsoft` implemented it and help me in understanding the same. that will be great.

```
damaged URL "obgv0%22%3e%3cscript%3ealert('XSS HACKED')%3c%2fscript%3et48bw"
```

1. Need help in solving the problem in `.net 2.0` application
2. Need support in understanding the way `Microsoft` implemented the fix for newer versions of `.net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have removed the cookies from the page and implement the server side validation to solve the vulnerability.

This is not a suggested solution for all the XSS issues. Solutions is Vulnerability Specific.

Comment: Looks like, you have answered your own question, whereas your solution is itself a stopgap measure.